# Paypal Express Checkout API not charging the money after payment

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the Paypal Express Checkout API for processing Paypal and VISA payments.
My code redirects the user to the paypal page, and after presents form where authentication occurs.   Then I proceed with authentication and click the Pay Now button.
I am redirected to the return URL. Apparently everything seems to be ok, but I never receive the money on the merchant account and the money is never charged from the buyer account.

Here is my code for requesting the the token:

```
private function _proceed_to_paypal($total_amount = false, $id_order = false, $description = false) {

    if ($total_amount === false || $id_order === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->load->library('paypal_functions');

    $this->paypal_functions->init();

    // ==================================
    // PayPal Express Checkout Module
    // ==================================

    //'------------------------------------
    //' The paymentAmount is the total value of 
    //' the shopping cart, that was set 
    //' earlier in a session variable 
    //' by the shopping cart page
    //'------------------------------------
    $paymentAmount = $total_amount;

    //'------------------------------------
    //' The currencyCodeType and paymentType 
    //' are set to the selections made on the Integration Assistant 
    //'------------------------------------
    $currencyCodeType = "EUR";
    $paymentType = "Sale";

    //'------------------------------------
    //' The returnURL is the location where buyers return to when a
    //' payment has been succesfully authorized.
    //'
    //' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
    //'------------------------------------
    $returnURL = site_url('payment/success');

    //'------------------------------------
    //' The cancelURL is the location buyers are sent to when they hit the
    //' cancel button during authorization of payment during the PayPal flow
    //'
    //' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
    //'------------------------------------
    $cancelURL = site_url('payment/cancel');

    //'------------------------------------
    //' Calls the SetExpressCheckout API call
    //'
    //' The CallShortcutExpressCheckout function is defined in the file PayPalFunctions.php,
    //' it is included at the top of this file.
    //'-------------------------------------------------
    $resArray = $this->paypal_functions->CallShortcutExpressCheckout ($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL, $description);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING") {
        $this->paypal_functions->RedirectToPayPal($resArray["TOKEN"]);
    } else  {


        $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
        $ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
        $ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
        $ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

        echo "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. ";
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg;
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg;
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode;
        echo '<br />';
    }

}
```

The paypal_functions Lib:

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Paypal_functions { 


private $PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
private $PROXY_PORT = '808';

// signals the test mode
private $SandboxFlag = false;


/* Paypal credentials */ 
private $API_UserName="xxx";
private $API_Password="xxx";
private $API_Signature="xxx";


// BN Code  is only applicable for partners
private $sBNCode = "PP-ECWizard";

private $USE_PROXY = false;
private $version = 0;

private $API_Endpoint;
private $PAYPAL_URL;


private $gv_ApiErrorURL;






/*  
' Define the PayPal Redirect URLs.  
'   This is the URL that the buyer is first sent to do authorize payment with their paypal account
'   change the URL depending if you are testing on the sandbox or the live PayPal site
'
' For the sandbox, the URL is       https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
' For the live site, the URL is        https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
*/

public function init() {
    if ($this->SandboxFlag == true) {
        $this->API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
        $this->PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    } else {
        $this->API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
        $this->PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    }

    $this->USE_PROXY = false;
    $this->version= "93";


}



/* An express checkout transaction starts with a token, that
   identifies to PayPal your transaction
   In this example, when the script sees a token, the script
   knows that the buyer has already authorized payment through
   paypal.  If no token was found, the action is to send the buyer
   to PayPal to first authorize payment
   */

/*   
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
' Inputs:  
'       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
'       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
'       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
'       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
'       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
*/
public function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL, $description) {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

    $nvpstr="&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=". $paymentAmount;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;

    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&SOLUTIONTYPE=" . 'Sole';
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&LANDINGPAGE=" . 'Billing';

    //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    //' Make the API call to PayPal
    //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
    //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $resArray = $this->hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
        $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
        $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
    }

    return $resArray;
}

/*   
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
' Inputs:  
'       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
'       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
'       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
'       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
'       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
'       shipToName:     the Ship to name entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToStreet:       the Ship to Street entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToCity:         the Ship to City entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToState:        the Ship to State entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToCountryCode:  the Code for Ship to Country entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToZip:          the Ship to ZipCode entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToStreet2:      the Ship to Street2 entered on the merchant's site
'       phoneNum:           the phoneNum  entered on the merchant's site
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
*/
public function CallMarkExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, 
                                  $cancelURL, $shipToName, $shipToStreet, $shipToCity, $shipToState,
                                  $shipToCountryCode, $shipToZip, $shipToStreet2, $phoneNum
                                ) {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

    $nvpstr="&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=". $paymentAmount;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&ADDROVERRIDE=1";
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=" . $shipToName;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=" . $shipToStreet;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=" . $shipToStreet2;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=" . $shipToCity;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=" . $shipToState;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=" . $shipToCountryCode;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=" . $shipToZip;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=" . $phoneNum;

    $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
    $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

    //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    //' Make the API call to PayPal
    //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
    //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $resArray=hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
        $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
        $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
    }

    return $resArray;
}

/*
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API Call.
'
' Inputs:  
'       None
' Returns: 
'       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function GetShippingDetails( $token ) {
    //'--------------------------------------------------------------
    //' At this point, the buyer has completed authorizing the payment
    //' at PayPal.  The function will call PayPal to obtain the details
    //' of the authorization, incuding any shipping information of the
    //' buyer.  Remember, the authorization is not a completed transaction
    //' at this state - the buyer still needs an additional step to finalize
    //' the transaction
    //'--------------------------------------------------------------

    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //' Build a second API request to PayPal, using the token as the
    //'  ID to get the details on the payment authorization
    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $nvpstr="&TOKEN=" . $token;

    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //' Make the API call and store the results in an array.  
    //' If the call was a success, show the authorization details, and provide
    //'     an action to complete the payment.  
    //' If failed, show the error
    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $resArray=hash_call("GetExpressCheckoutDetails",$nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {   
        $_SESSION['payer_id'] = $resArray['PAYERID'];
    } 
    return $resArray;
}

/*
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API Call.
'
' Inputs:  
'       sBNCode:    The BN code used by PayPal to track the transactions from a given shopping cart.
' Returns: 
'       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
*/
public function ConfirmPayment( $FinalPaymentAmt )
{
    /* Gather the information to make the final call to
       finalize the PayPal payment.  The variable nvpstr
       holds the name value pairs
       */


    //Format the other parameters that were stored in the session from the previous calls   
    $token              = urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
    $paymentType        = urlencode($_SESSION['PaymentType']);
    $currencyCodeType   = urlencode($_SESSION['currencyCodeType']);
    $payerID            = urlencode($_SESSION['payer_id']);

    $serverName         = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

    $nvpstr  = '&TOKEN=' . $token . '&PAYERID=' . $payerID . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=' . $paymentType . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=' . $FinalPaymentAmt;
    $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=' . $currencyCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName; 

     /* Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
        If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        */
    $resArray=hash_call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment",$nvpstr);

    /* Display the API response back to the browser.
       If the response from PayPal was a success, display the response parameters'
       If the response was an error, display the errors received using APIError.php.
       */
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

    return $resArray;
}

/*
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  This function makes a DoDirectPayment API call
'
' Inputs:  
'       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
'       paymentAmount:      total value of the shopping cart
'       currencyCode:       currency code value the PayPal API
'       firstName:          first name as it appears on credit card
'       lastName:           last name as it appears on credit card
'       street:             buyer's street address line as it appears on credit card
'       city:               buyer's city
'       state:              buyer's state
'       countryCode:        buyer's country code
'       zip:                buyer's zip
'       creditCardType:     buyer's credit card type (i.e. Visa, MasterCard ... )
'       creditCardNumber:   buyers credit card number without any spaces, dashes or any other characters
'       expDate:            credit card expiration date
'       cvv2:               Card Verification Value 
'       
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       
' Returns: 
'       The NVP Collection object of the DoDirectPayment Call Response.
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
*/


public function DirectPayment( $paymentType, $paymentAmount, $creditCardType, $creditCardNumber,
                        $expDate, $cvv2, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $city, $state, $zip, 
                        $countryCode, $currencyCode )
{
    //Construct the parameter string that describes DoDirectPayment
    $nvpstr = "&AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCode;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CREDITCARDTYPE=" . $creditCardType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&ACCT=" . $creditCardNumber;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&EXPDATE=" . $expDate;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CVV2=" . $cvv2;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&FIRSTNAME=" . $firstName;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&LASTNAME=" . $lastName;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STREET=" . $street;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CITY=" . $city;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STATE=" . $state;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&COUNTRYCODE=" . $countryCode;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&IPADDRESS=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $resArray=hash_call("DoDirectPayment", $nvpstr);

    return $resArray;
}


/**
  * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * hash_call: Function to perform the API call to PayPal using API signature
  * @methodName is name of API  method.
  * @nvpStr is nvp string.
  * returns an associtive array containing the response from the server.
  * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function hash_call($methodName,$nvpStr)
{
    //declaring of global variables
    /*
    global $API_Endpoint, $this->version, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature;
    global $this->USE_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT;
    global $gv_ApiErrorURL;
    global $sBNCode;
    */

    //setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //if USE_PROXY constant set to TRUE in Constants.php, then only proxy will be enabled.
   //Set proxy name to PROXY_HOST and port number to PROXY_PORT in constants.php 
    if($this->USE_PROXY)
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->PROXY_HOST. ":" . $this->PROXY_PORT); 

    //NVPRequest for submitting to server
    $nvpreq="METHOD=" . urlencode($methodName) . "&VERSION=" . urlencode($this->version) . "&PWD=" . urlencode($this->API_Password) . "&USER=" . urlencode($this->API_UserName) . "&SIGNATURE=" . urlencode($this->API_Signature) . $nvpStr . "&BUTTONSOURCE=" . urlencode($this->sBNCode);

    //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    //getting response from server
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //convrting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
    $nvpResArray = $this->deformatNVP($response);
    $nvpReqArray = $this->deformatNVP($nvpreq);
    $_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;

    if (curl_errno($ch)) 
    {
        // moving to display page to display curl errors
          //$_SESSION['curl_error_no']=curl_errno($ch) ;
          //$_SESSION['curl_error_msg']=curl_error($ch);

          //Execute the Error handling module to display errors. 
    } 
    else 
    {
         //closing the curl
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    return $nvpResArray;
}

/*'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Purpose: Redirects to PayPal.com site.
 Inputs:  NVP string.
 Returns: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function RedirectToPayPal ( $token )
{
    //global $PAYPAL_URL;

    // Redirect to paypal.com here
    $payPalURL = $this->PAYPAL_URL . $token . '&useraction=commit';
    header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
    exit;
}


/*'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This function will take NVPString and convert it to an Associative Array and it will decode the response.
  * It is usefull to search for a particular key and displaying arrays.
  * @nvpstr is NVPString.
  * @nvpArray is Associative Array.
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */
public  function deformatNVP($nvpstr)
{
    $intial=0;
    $nvpArray = array();

    while(strlen($nvpstr))
    {
        //postion of Key
        $keypos= strpos($nvpstr,'=');
        //position of value
        $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr,'&'): strlen($nvpstr);

        /*getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array*/
        $keyval=substr($nvpstr,$intial,$keypos);
        $valval=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
        //decoding the respose
        $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] =urldecode( $valval);
        $nvpstr=substr($nvpstr,$valuepos+1,strlen($nvpstr));
     }
    return $nvpArray;
}

}
```

PS - This is the result of echoing **$nvpstr** before:

```
$resArray = $this->hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
```

-

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=0.01&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&
RETURNURL=http://localhost/site/payment/success&
CANCELURL=http://localhost/site/payment/cancel&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR&
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the paypal API says the transaction took place, you need to check with paypal

Comment: Paypal doesn't say that. After clicking Pay Now, appears a loader with the text "processing payment", and then I'm redirected to the RETURNURL.

Comment: can you add $this->paypal_functions->SandboxFlag = false;

Comment: jdog.. it's already set to false.

Comment: Here you can find tutorial about "How to integrate your website with PayPal" http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-integrate-your-website-with-paypal-using-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're only completing the first part of the process.  Express Checkout consists of 3 separate calls:

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

No money is processed until you've completed the final DoExpressCheckoutPayment call.

Review the [Express Checkout Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) for more details on this.

Comment: That was precisely the problem. Thks a lot!

Comment: Here you can find tutorial about "How to integrate your website with PayPal" http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-integrate-your-website-with-paypal-using-php/